# Is there a browser addon to check for duplicate tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser-tabs

Is there a Firefox addon to check if a tab is already opened?

For example, I have a lot of tabs usually and I open several a time as I read a page. Is there a way to say for example if I've already opened `www.stackoverflow.com` in a tab, and I click on a link to `www.stackoverflow.com`, it will jump me to that open tab instead of creating another tab with Stack Overflow?

Or, I've seen there are hierarchical tab views for Firefox, does such exist for Chrome?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few extensions in Chrome that cleans up duplicate tabs such as:

- [Prevent Duplicate Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/prevent-duplicate-tabs/eangilbdbecadgeclbehnkibpmedaoih/),
- [Tab Dupectomy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-dupectomy/nkkedbpcfdogedipgdhgeknjdphaplbk?hl=en) (licence: [LGPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html), see: [GitHub mirror](https://github.com/gcode-mirror/tab-dupectomy)).

Comment: I was using Tab Dupectomy for a long time and it was very good. But today I noticed that it has gone! Is there anyone who know what happened? Can you still use that extension?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 4.0 lets you type in an open Tab URL or name into the AwesomeBar to switch to it.
[image: Firefox 4.0's tab switching. Image from Mozilla.]